# Solve $\frac1{x(x+1)}+\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)}+\frac{1}{(x+4)(x+5)}=\frac{5}{24}$

Tags: polynomials

This is taken from one of the TAU entry tests (I have one in 2 weeks :) ) So, I don't really recognize anything special here except that there's some similarity between some pairs of denominators, my intuition is telling me to just multipy everything and try to solve but it looks like a big dead polynomial. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition will show you something cool

Comment: $$\frac1{2\times3}=\frac12-\frac13, \frac1{3\times4}=\frac13-\frac14,\ldots$$

Comment: Should there be a $\frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)}$ term?